# Xamarin forms DisplayAlert not showing when called from a function called by a delegate

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, delegates

When I call Greet from inside the size function DisplayAlert displays an alert as expected However when it is called from the delegate after an event it will Log to the output with the correct name (Greet Has been Called) but the DisplayAlert does not show.

```
   public class CustomPage : ContentPage
   {
         ...

        protected override void OnValidSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            ...

            Greet("Test");

            app.FB.GetName();

            app.FB.NameRecieved += (s,e) =>
            {
                Greet(e.Name);  
            };

        }

        public void Greet(string name)
        {
            Utils.Log("Hey " + name);
            DisplayAlert("Hey " + name, "Welcome", "OK");
        }

    }
```

The Code above outputs "Hey Test" and then an alert comes up saying "Hey Test, Welcome" with an OK button then it outputs "Hey Leo" (which is correct because that is the name from the Facebook account) but then no Alert shows.

Comment: You (probably) need to force DisplayAlert to run on the UI Thread.  Try using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is NameReceived fired inside GetName function?

Maybe you need to put app.FB.GetName() after the "+={...};" block.

If nameReceived is correctly fired maybe Greet is not running on ui thread,
try wrap your display code in

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
 DisplayAlert("Hey " + name, "Welcome", "OK");
});
```

as described [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(System.Action)/)

Comment: Thanks Mauro this worked! NameRecieved is fired inside GetName and although it works with the code in either order (Maybe there is a delay for the event being fired?) you are right that I should subscribe to the event first. After wrapping my display code in the UI thread it all works, i'm a little new to multithreading so it didn't cross my mind. Cheers, Leo.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a `PageBase` class that implements `DisplayAlert` and wraps it in `BeingInvokeOnMainThread` so that you do not have to keep re-writing it:

```
public class PageBase : ContentPage
{        
    public void DisplayAlert(string message,string title, string button)
    {
         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
              DisplayAlert(message, title, button);
              });
    }

}
```

Comment: Good idea! This makes it much simpler if I want more than one display alert.